# DbContext per HTTP Request But Avoid Dependency on HttpContext in Data Layer

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, httpcontext, dbcontext, data-layer

I've been thinking of how I could use one instance of a `DbContext` per `HttpRequest` in a layered application. One of the solutions I came up with would be to create an `HttpModule` that would initialize an instance of the context in `HttpContext.Current.Items` in the `BeginRequest` event handler and then dispose it in the `EndRequest` event handler.

The approach above poses a problem though: I need to reference System.Web in my data layer and business layer in order to get a hold of the stored `DbContext` instance. This is probably okay but I prefer to avoid going that route. What if I wanted to reference and use my data layer and business layers from a non-web application?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dependency injection. Simply create interface `IContextHolder` with method to get a context and inject the instance into your lower layer from the web application. The implementation of this interface will be different for different types of applications - it will wrap the access to the real storage for your context instance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solutions would be to wrap the access to the data context in a static property in a facade/gateway class.

This way, in a web application, the property could access the `HttpContext.Current.Items` and store the context there. On the other hand, if the http context is missing, you could implement any other lifetime management policy for a non-web application.

```
public static TheDbContext Current {
  get {
     if ( HttpContext.Current != null ) {
        // lifetime management for a web app
        // e.g. with the Items container
     }
     else {
        // lifetime management for a non-web app
     }
  }
}
```

The facade itself doesn't have to be a part of the data layer, you don't then reference `System.Web` in a data layer.